# dotnet 6 System.Text.Json Source Generation Delegate Type Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a class that contains a public Func property and a private readonly Action member variable. This class is included in the JsonSerializerContext class I'm implementing for source generation. When I build the project, the generated g.cs file throws a CS0149 error: Method name Expected.

I've tried assigning a DoNothing method to these items but still run into the same issue. I've also tried removing the Func and Action types and used a delegate type instead and have the same problem. Overall, I don't want either of these properties to be serialized or deserialized anyways, but the source generator doesn't seem to care.

Here are the declarations of the members:

```
[JsonIgnore] public Func<ICanRenderTable, object> SortingMethod { get; init; }
private readonly Action<IConvertible> OnValueChangeCallback;
```

The error is this:
`Error  CS0149  Method name expected    System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\BGCSourceGenerator.ActionIConvertible.g.cs  25`

`Error  CS0149  Method name expected    System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator\BGCSourceGenerator.FuncICanRenderTableObject.g.cs 25`

If I remove the class from the source generator context I've created, then it compiles without issue. I haven't been able to find this issue specifically on either the SO or the issues board for the system.text.json repo. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it might be wise to open a defect report on the repo.

Comment: After consulting with a colleague who reproduced the problem, I think I'm going to do that. I haven't seen this issue posted yet. Thanks!

Comment: There's an issue posted here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62354

Comment: I created that issue. Forgot to post it here. Thanks!